# Python Regex String Replace

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to use Regex to replace a string like this:

```
The quick #[brown]brown#[clear] fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

with

```
The quick <a style="color:#3B170B">brown<a style="color:#FFFFFF"> fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

However the color code is picked out of a like as such

```
color_list = dict(
                 brown = "#3B170B",
                 .....
                 clear = "#FFFFFF",
                 )
```

Comment: @Eric At this point not much, I have tried using `re.sub()` however I cannot to my knowledge use `re.group()` to pull out the partiular name of the color I want.

Comment: Do you have control over your input string? That would be a good situation in which to use string formatting if so.

Comment: @RocketDonkey No I don't have control over the input string.

Comment: you miss `</a>` closing tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is what you need.  It takes either a replacement string or a function as its second argument.  Here we provide a function because part of generating the replacement string needs is a dictionary lookup.

```
re.sub(r'#\[(.+?)\]', lambda m:'<a style="color:%s">' % colors[m.group(1)], s)
```

Comment: I am finding the `re.sub` function does not seem to work even when I implement something such as `re.sub(r'#\[brown\]', colors['brown'], s)` which should return the string to `The quick brown #3B170Bfox#[clear] jumped over the lazy dog.`

Comment: I renamed `color_list` to `colors`.  Are you forgetting to update that name?

Comment: No in fact I used a completely different name in my code and was thrown an error to fix it, after the fix there was no change in the string.

Comment: @Blackninja543:  Are you assigning the result of `re.sub` back to your string?

Answer (score 0):

A crude pseudo-python solution would look like this:

```
for key, value in color_list.items()
  key_matcher = dict_key_to_re_pattern( key )
  formatted_value = '<a style...{0}...>'.format( value )
  re.sub( key_matcher, formatted_value, your_input_string )


def dict_key_to_re_pattern( key ):
   return r'#[{0}]'.format( key )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line of fine python should help:

```
reduce(lambda txt, i:txt.replace('#[%s]'%i[0],'<a style="color=%s;">'%i[1]),colors.items(),txt)
```

Comment: Looks like Haskell-derived perfectly unreadable one-liner : ) . Although I like the idea